# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Error'

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm currently migrating a project from Objective C toSwift 5.1, and I have several functions using the "do something - success - failure" structure. When migrating with Swiftify to Swift, I get the error:

**Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Error'**

in the line with "if let error = error { print...".

```
func forgotPassword(_ jsonDict: inout [AnyHashable : Any], success: NetworkManagerSuccess, failure: NetworkManagerFailure) {

        manager?.post("custom_api_url", parameters: jsonDict, progress: nil, success: { operation, responseObject in
            if let responseObject = responseObject {
                print("\(responseObject)")
            }
            success(responseObject)
        }, failure: { operation, error in
          if  let  error = error {
            print("\n\nFailed: Error:\n: \(error)")

            failure(error)
        })
    }
```

The same piece of code in Objective C is the following:

```
- (void)forgotPassword:(NSMutableDictionary *)jsonDict success:(NetworkManagerSuccess)success failure:(NetworkManagerFailure)failure {

    [manager POST:"custom_url_api" parameters:jsonDict progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
        success(responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"\n\nFailed: Error:\n: %@", error);
        failure(error);
    }];
}
```

Can anybody please help me solve it?

Thanks!